# Modelling unique relationships in UML class diagrams

Tags: associations, uml, unique, diagram

This question is about UML class diagrams in the analysis phase.
I've made up a minimal example for illustration purposes:

[image: UML diagram]

A ticket is valid for one seat and one specific seminar.
A seat can be assigned to multiple tickets, but only to one unique ticket/seminar combination.
(The same goes for the seminar and a unique ticket/seat combination.)

The diagram does not reflect that.  I've marked the wrong multiplicities in red.

What options (the more the better) do you know to model the requirement correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That kind of commutative consistency check cannot be expressed either by UML or Entity Relationship diagrams. By the way, you can't express either that, from a ticket instance, the path ticket -> seat -> seminar location must lead to the same instance as ticket -> seminar -> seminar location.

Formally, the multiplicities you marked in red are correct. A seat sees more than one ticket, just for different seminars, and the other way round.

So the only solution I can offer is to include the requirement in the textual specification of those relationships. That's not a bad thing, as any finite set of graphical symbols could only express a subset of all possible requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Ticket could be an association class between seat and seminar. Or just use OCL to express this constraint

Answer (score 0):

"you can't express either that, from a ticket instance, the path ticket -> seat -> seminar location must lead to the same instance as ticket -> seminar -> seminar location"

1) OCL - context Ticket inv: seminar.seminarLocation=seat.seminarLocation

2) draw Seat, Seminar and association class Ticket between Seat and Seminar - into SeminarLocation(Figure 13-70 http://msdl.cs.mcgill.ca/people/tfeng/docs/The%20Unified%20Modeling%20Language%20Reference%20Manual.pdf or Figure 14-84 http://www.utdallas.edu/~chung/Fujitsu/UML_2.0/Rumbaugh--UML_2.0_Reference_CD.pdf)